# Best way to convert String to json in Android(Java)?

Tags: java, android, json, string, webview

I am doing a statistics application using a 3rd party API. what I got from the API; json from webview with userAgent. I need to take this as a string and then convert it to json, but when I set it to the string value, I get the error "constant string too long". I found some solution but I don't think it's the best method.What is the best way to keep a big String in a variable?

Thanks for any help.

my convert code below here

```
    Gson g = new Gson();

   User user = g.fromJson(sampleJson, User.class);

    Log.d("comingData",user.getGlobal_blacklist_sample());
```

My json has much more than user(500+) showed inside Users array  (100000+ characters)

Added sample Json string below here

```
    {
"sections": null,
"global_blacklist_sample": null,
"users": [{
"pk": 1111111111,
    "username": "sample_username",
    "full_name": "Sample Name :)",
    "is_private": false,
    "profile_pic_url": "https://sammple_pic",
    "profile_pic_id": "2315322835352130707_36052201610",
    "is_verified": false,
    "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false,
    "latest_reel_media": 0
},  {
"pk": 22222,
    "username": "sample_username2",
    "full_name": "Sample Name2 :)",
    "is_private": false,
    "profile_pic_url": "https://sammple_pic2",
    "profile_pic_id": "22222222222",
    "is_verified": false,
    "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false,
    "latest_reel_media": 0
}]
```

}

Comment: please share your string to json conversion code and the json string

Comment: @MdGolamRahmanTushar I added my json sample

Comment: what's the solution you found? have a look at this link: https://www.baeldung.com/java-constant-string-too-long-error

Comment: yes i found it too, but i want to do it without txt file. @MdGolamRahmanTushar